# How to add constant value to a certain columns for a limited number of rows and set the precision of the decimal number

Tags: awk

I want to add a constant value to the third (and second) columns from row and 10 to line number 20. How can do it? I have tried this code but it does seem to work at all. It gives me the same output file. Could someone explain why and how does this work better, please?

```
 awk '{if(NR>9) $3=$3+1; print $0}' <file_input  > file_output
```

Do you think there is a better solution instead of using awk in this case?
Let me know, thank you.
Best wishes to everyone.

This is the head of the input_file

```
SCAN U=3
1.0
+7.2621642310  +0.0000000000  +0.0000000000
+0.0000000000  +7.4947599620  +0.0000000000
-0.4702406680  +0.0000000000 +50.5797763000
O W
56 20
Selective
Cartesian
+6.9271068928 +7.2623406786 33.3906 T T T
```

...and then it continues like that
The expected output should be like:

```
SCAN U=3
1.0
+7.2621642310  +0.0000000000  +0.0000000000
+0.0000000000  +7.4947599620  +0.0000000000
-0.4702406680  +0.0000000000 +50.5797763000
O W
56 20
Selective
Cartesian
+6.9271068928 +8.2623406786 34.3906 T T T
```

And how can I set the precision of the decimal number of the result of the operation?

Comment: I tested with your sample file and code and it does alter the third field, that looks correct. The answer would be `awk 'NR>9 && NR<21{$2=$2+1;$3=$3+1}{print}'`, but since your attempt does not work, I wonder if this would.

Comment: Why are you using redirection to read the input file? You can just state `awk ' ... ' input_file > output_file`.

Comment: @Quasímodo while I agree with your solution, isn't there a lost of precision in second filed ? (e.g. **8.26234** instead of **+8.2623406786**)

Comment: @Archemar Indeed, I didn't pay enough attention to the details. In any case, feel free to post an answer. I have just suggested that for the OP to try.

Comment: Actually awk 'NR>9 && NR<21{$2=$2+1;$3=$3+1}{print}' <file_input > file_output now seemed to work fine. The form of the output depend on the software which gives me the result, not on me. Thank you very much!

Comment: To preserve the original precision of each field: `match($3,/[[:digit:]]*$/); $3 = sprintf("%+.*f",RLENGTH,1+$3);`

Comment: If the script in your question doesn't change the value of $3 on line 10 of your input as you claim then your awk is severely broken which, frankly, I highly doubt. Please post a reproducible example of your actual problem if you'd like help with it.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
awk 'NR>9 && NR<21{
  printf "%s %+.10f %.4f %s %s %s\n",$1,1+$2,1+$3,$4,$5,$6; 
  next ; }
 {print}'
```

where

- `printf` is used for formating
- `%+.10f` to have 10 precision floating with leading **+**
- use a fixed number of field
- can be one lined, I split for reading purpose

---

Note depending on you `locale`, you may need to prefix with `LANG=C`

e.g.

```
LANG=C awk '...'
```

with my french local lines came up as

```
+6.9271068928 +8,0000000000 34,0000 T T T
```

Comment: I actually need the separator to be a dot . and not a comma , 
How can I do it? thank you very muche for your answer

Comment: but why do you have only zero after the comma?

Comment: `$3 += 1` works. More surprisingly, `++$3` also works, and C will also increment doubles etc.

Comment: In fact, you can omit the increments: just list the fields as`1+$2, 1+$3,..`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant That was clever, I reported it

Comment: @Archemar I have tried but the precision remains the same, still on the 4th decimal number after the dot, not more

Comment: Would you care to edit your question with value of LANG and any environment variables starting with LC_ ?

Comment: @computational wrt [but why do you have only zero after the comma?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612179/how-to-add-constant-value-to-a-certain-columns-for-a-limited-number-of-rows-and#comment1143111_612184) - because in Archemar's locale comma `,` is the decimal separator, not dot `.`, and so awk converts the numeric-string `33.3906` to a number `33` before doing the `+1` just like it would if the input string was `33#3906` or anything else that had a numeric part at the front. If the input was `33,3906` in Archemars locale **then** the whole string would be recognized as a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>9 && NR<21{$2=$2+1;$3=$3+1}{print}' <file_input  > file_output
```

Credit to [Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/388654/quas%c3%admodo)

Comment: You don't often see values with positives preceded by '+'. I tested it with GNU/awk and it works, but I wondered what version of awk did not work for the OP. This solution does not output the explicit '+', so I wondered how picky any readers of the file might be about it.

Comment: actually this is true, but for my aim it fine, the program can read it without problem. thank you.

Comment: If the script in your question doesn't alter $3 on line 10 of your input as you say in your question but the script in your answer does alter it than your awk is severely broken since both scripts do exactly the same thing for $3 on line 10.